# How can I fetch the facebook profile picture of an authenticated user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made a website using php where I can fetch a users facebook user id, email id, and fb id and some other stuff. Is it possible for me to fetch a profile picture from facebook, so the user doesn't need to upload a picture when they enter the system?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to describe what you have tried so far and how it has failed.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i tried to fetch profile picture from facebook using my app id and secret key. But i got only facebbok id, user name, email address.I used SDK method to fetch these information

Answer (score 0):

You can get the facebook profile photo using the following URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture
```

So for the currently authenticated user you just need to use the user ID returned in the SDK:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$user}/picture";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i ll try this out. but i have a question is it possible to fetch picture from pic folder of facebook. i can fetch name from database but is it possible to fetch picture.

Comment: If you have the URL of the photo, you can just download it using `file_get_contents($url)` or something